# Deploy multiple microservices depending on each other for packages to docker container

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I have to deploy *microservices* in java to docker container and these microservices depend on each other for packages to build. Like application a has the base packages required by other applications b,c and d so i **can't do mvn clean install docker:build** to build b,c and d without a. I am new to docker and can someone suggest me how to approach this problem.

*I am using docker plugins in pom file and then using mvn clean install -d docker:build to make docker image.*

Comment: You do the build first, then deployed the built jar into the docker container.

Comment: besides the fundamental flaw of dependent microsvcs, your build needs refactoring. either pull out the package required in a library and add dependencies to that or consider a module build since your docker containers are one microservice

Comment: I was thinking along the lines if docker containers could access each other but i am not clear how to follow through this process.

Comment: Containers can't access each others' file systems.

Answer (score 1):

There are different solutions to this problem:

- Using maven (or gradle) you can create a maven project for common classes and import it in the other project as a dependency
- Duplicate code in different projects. While this seems not a good solution it completely separate dependency between projects. Each project must be seen from the others as a black box so you shouldn't know anything about its internal code. For example You should be able to change the programming language of a single docker without affecting the beahaviour of the whole environment.

---

Updated answer: To use the maven dependencies the steps are:

- Find in project A the classes used by project B
- Delete this classes from project A
- Create a new project C
- Add the classes deleted in project A to the project C
- Build and install the project C (mvn -install)
- Change the pom of project A to use the dependency of project C
- Build project A
- Change the pom of project B to use the dependency of project C
- Build project B
- Use the unique jar A.jar to create the docker image for A
- Use the unique jar B.jar to create the docker image for B

Comment: I am adding required dependencies in our .m2 repository for the common dependencies but since docker containers are independent i am not able to do the same here.

Comment: @RahulAnand you must create a jar having all the dependencies inside it. You must use the depencies at compile time. Not when you build docker images. The jar added to the docker already has the related dependencies, so the build of the docker is very simple (you need only to copy a single jar inside it)

Comment: I am not able to build my application image(application b) because it tries to find the jar which has dependencies(application a) required by b and it give me the error : Failed to collect dependencies at  app:commonapp:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @RahulAnand you must extract from project A classes used by project B and create a new project C hosting this classes. Then you need to import the new project C in both A and B

Comment: @RahulAnand check the updated answer explaining each step.

Comment: Thanks, i will try out this approach.